# Image similarity using Tensorflow or PyTorch

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, pytorch

I want to compare two images for similarity. Since my purpose is to match a given image against a massive collection of images, I want to run the comparisons on GPU.

I came across `tf.image.ssim` and `tf.image.psnr` functions but I am unable to find and working examples only. The solutions in PyTorch is also appreciated. Since I don't have a good understanding of CUDA and C language, I am hesitant to try kernels in PyCuda.

Will it be helpful in terms of processing if I read the entire image collection and store as Tensorflow Records for future processing?

Any guidance or solution, greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit:- I am matching images of same size only. I don't want to do mere histogram match. I want to do SSIM or PSNR implementation for image similarity. So, I am assuming it would be similar in color, content etc

Comment: I think that providing the parameters on which you want to define similarity will help you in getting a better answer, are you trying to match on size, color distribution, contents, ...etc. Try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the example on the tensorflow doc page ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/ssim)):

```
im1 = tf.decode_png('path/to/im1.png')
im2 = tf.decode_png('path/to/im2.png')
print(tf.image.ssim(im1, im2, max_val=255))
```

This should work on latest version of tensorflow. If you use older versions tf.image.ssim will return a tensor (print will not give you a value), but you can call .run() to evaluate it.

Comment: I read through the docs, but how do we get the percentage of similarity from the returned Tensor? And can you add some explanation for `max_val` argument?

Comment: max_val is what is the range of values in your image. Likely 255 is good enough.

Comment: Check out the paper mentioned. Not only you should find what you're looking for, but you might get a better overview of how it works and potential pitfalls.

Comment: are you referring to the docs link attached in answer or some other paper? and any idea about percentage of similarly? thats what i am primarily looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implementation of PSNR or SSIM in PyTorch. You can either implement them yourself or use a third-party package, like [`piqa`](https://github.com/francois-rozet/piqa) which I have developed.

Assuming you already have `torch` and `torchvision` installed, you can get it with

```bash
pip install piqa
```

Then for the image comparison

```py
import torch

from torchvision import transforms
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open('path/to/im1.png')
im2 = Image.open('path/to/im2.png')

transform = transforms.ToTensor()

x = transform(im1).unsqueeze(0).cuda() # .cuda() for GPU
y = transform(im2).unsqueeze(0).cuda()

from piqa import PSNR, SSIM

psnr = PSNR()
ssim = SSIM().cuda()

print('PSNR:', psnr(x, y))
print('SSIM:', ssim(x, y))
```